# How to convert a React array to a JSON object with same key and value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of values in my React app `[profile1, profile2, profile3]` read from a database and I need to convert these to a json object that can be used in a third party component. The resultant json needs to be:

```
{profile1: "profile1", profile2: "profile2", profile3: "profile2"}
```

I am unfamiliar with JavaScript and React.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: FWIW: JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: Also there is no such thing as a "React array". It's just an array.

Comment: What is `profile1`, `profile2`, etc? A variable? A string? In your example it looks like variables. It's usually not possible to get the name of a variable. Please provide a more complete example.

Comment: No need to lash out. The title says *"Need help converting **a React array** to a JSON object with same key and value please"* .  *"I also said that they were values from a database"* But that doesn't tell me whether you are getting the whole array from the database or whether you are putting three values from the database into an array. Lots of people say one thing and mean another. That's why we comment and ask for clarification, to make sure we are all on the same page. You could have just clarified that the data you have is (maybe) `["profile1", "profile2", "profile3"]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
    const object = {};
    const array = ["one", "two", "three"];

    array.forEach(v => object[v] = v);
    console.log(object);
```

Comment: please give answer in proper detail. Check this link for details.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: This is perfect thanks for you help - I knew it would be simple just didn't know the syntax

Comment: Don't use `.map` to iterate over the array. Use `for` loop or `forEach`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing something like this

```js
const profiles = ['profile1', 'profile2', 'profile3'];
let obj = {};

profiles.forEach(profile => obj[profile] = profile);

console.log(obj);
```